# Checking to see if SharePoint web exists

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am writing an event handler that, on ItemAdded, checks to see if a site exists, then creates a site with the given URL or with an alternate URL.  I already wrote something similar but I was attempting to clean up my code for the site exist check into the method below.

```
    private string CheckSiteExists(SPWeb web, string siteURL, string webURL)
    {
        //Counter for our alternate URL
        int i = 0;
        //Open original URL
        SPWeb tempweb = web.Site.OpenWeb(webURL + "/" + siteURL);
        //Check if site exists
        if (tempweb.Exists == false)
        {
            do
            {
                i++;
                tempweb = web.Site.OpenWeb(webURL + "/" + siteURL + "_" + i);
            }
            while (tempweb.Exists == false);
            //Dispose of our web
            tempweb.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            tempweb.Dispose();
            //If site does not exist, return original URL
            return siteURL;
        }
        //If site does exist, return original url plus counter
        return siteURL + "_" + i;
    }
```

I decided to test what I have and found that w3wp went from 0% CPU usage to 50-80% and stayed there until I killed it manually.  I'm guessing that my do while statement isn't acting as I think it should and it's just looping to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to be finding the first URL that matches a web that does exist, not the first matching a web that doesn't exist:

- You're checking `tempweb.Exists == false` rather than `== true`
- You're only disposing, and returning the URL, after `tempweb.Exists` is true.

If no web exists, this will get stuck in a very long loop.

Comment: Crap.  I stared at this for so long and didn't notice that.  Thanks!

Comment: you're not using booleans correctly if you are comparing them to true or false...